# Referencing unitialized values in trait body Scala

Tags: scala

How come the following code doesn't raise a reference error?

```
trait T1 {
  println( "  in T1: x = " + x )
  val x=1
  println( "  in T1: x = " + x )
}

class C12 extends T1 {
  println( "  in C12: c = " + c )
  val c="C12"
  println( "  in C12: c = " + c )
}

new C12
```

Instead, it seems that `x` defaults to 0 and `c` defaults to `null`. How does this work in scala? When are these variables initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As explained in the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html):

> The scope of a name introduced by a declaration or definition is the whole statement sequence containing the binding. However, there is a restriction on forward references in blocks: In a statement sequence `s1…sn` making up a block, if a simple name in `si` refers to an entity defined by `sj` where `j≥i`, then for all `sk` between and including `si` and `sj`, `sk` cannot be a variable definition. If `sk` is a value definition, it must be lazy.

Trait and class bodies aren't blocks, so there is no forward reference restriction here.

> When are these variables initialized?

The statements (including `val` initializations) are simply executed in order.